# Configuring Test Results Analyzer Jenkins Plugin for a pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pytest, test-results

I am trying to configure my Jenkins pipeline project that runs pytest tests with the Jenkins Test Results Analyzer plugin. Everything online says that under the job configuration at post build actions add the plugin, but since this is not in the pipeline configuration, how do I configure the plugin to analyze my test results?